# Install Numpy for Python-3.4.2 using Conda on Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS

Tags: numpy, conda

I installed conda properly.

Now I want to use Numpy along with the Python-3.4.2 that comes by default with it.

Here is what I run and what I got as an error:

```
 conda install python3-numpy
Fetching package metadata: ....
Error: No packages found in current linux-32 channels matching: python3-numpy

Did you mean one of these?

    python-ntlm

You can search for this package on Binstar with

    binstar search -t conda python3-numpy
begueradj@begueradj-HP-Compaq-6510b-KE130ET-ABF:/home$ binstar search -t conda python3-numpy
Using binstar api site https://api.binstar.org
Run 'binstar show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
No packages found
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms      
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
Found 0 packages
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conda, the package is just called `numpy`. Your conda environment should already have Python 3 in it. If it doesn't, you can create a new one with `conda create -n py3 python=3 numpy` and activate it with `source activate py3`.